# How to use an if statement after grep via pipe

Tags: bash

I am trying to find all instances of `"type":"FollowEvent"`, and then within those instances, if the string `"actor":` is not followed by `{`, then capture the string enclosed in `"` that comes immediately after `"actor":`. Else, capture the string enclosed in `"` that comes immediately after `"login:"`.

What I have so far:

```
zgrep -e '"type":"FollowEvent"' /path/to/dir/* | zgrep -o '"actor":(?!{)*' | cut -f2- -d: | cut -d',' -f1 > results_file.txt
```

What this does:

For all files in /path/to/dir, for all lines that contain `"type":"FollowEvent"`, find `"actor:"` not followed by `{`. Then take everything after the `:`, and before the next `,`. Put the results in `results_file.txt`.

A single line in the files that are being grep'd could look like this:

```
{"repo":{"url":"https://url","name":"/"},"type":"FollowEvent","public":true,"created_at":"2011-05-29","payload":{"target":{"gravatar_id":"73","id":64,"repos":35,"followers":58,"login":"username3"}},"actor":{"gravatar_id":"06","id":439,"url":"https://url","avatar_url":"https://.png","login":"username4"},"id":"14"}
```

or like this:

```
{"repo":{"url":"https://url/","name":"/"},"type":"FollowEvent","public":true,"created_at":"2011-04-01","payload":{"target":{"gravatar_id":"40","repos":2,"followers":1,"login":"username2"},"actor":"username1","actor_gravatar":"de4"},"actor":{"gravatar_id":"de4","id":716,"url":"https://url","avatar_url":"https://.png","login":"username2"},"id":"12"}
```

What I want:

a file containing only the usernames of actors. Here, I want, in `results_file.txt`:

```
username4
username1
```

Comment: You should give [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) a look. Available as a package on most distros.

Comment: It's not available to me.

Comment: How about Python and its json parser?

Comment: Or PHP and its json parser?

Comment: Really... don't parse json without a json parser. This is a trivial exercise with jq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say:

```
JSON='{"repo":{"url":"https://url","name":"/"},"type":"FollowEvent","public":true,"created_at":"2011-05-29","payload":{"target":{"gravatar_id":"73","id":64,"repos":35,"followers":58,"login":"username3"}},"actor":{"gravatar_id":"06","id":439,"url":"https://url","avatar_url":"https://.png","login":"username4"},"id":"14"}'
```

For a simple answer, I do suggest you to use `jq`: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

```
$ echo "$JSON" | jq -r '. | select(.type=="FollowEvent") | .actor.login'
username4
```

You can install it in most of distros with the default package manager.

Anyway if you need to do it with GNU tools.

```
$ echo "$JSON" | grep '"type":"FollowEvent"' | sed 's/.*"login":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/g'
username4
```

Comment: I can't install jq, so I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: Maybe: `echo "$JSON" | grep '"type":"FollowEvent"' | tr ',' '\n' | grep login | cut -d\" -f4`

Comment: Thank you @ton! The final command that worked was this, inspired by you: `zgrep -e '"type":"FollowEvent"' ./2011* | sed 's/.*"login":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/g' > results_file.txt`

Comment: One issue, though: this captures everything after "login", but there is more than one "login" on each line. I want the one specifically associated with "actor", not "payload".

Comment: What about? `echo "$JSON" | grep '"type":"FollowEvent"' | sed 's/.*"actor":.*"login":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/g'` ?